# How to submit vue-google-maps placeInput to server?

Tags: php, laravel, google-maps, laravel-5, vue.js

I have a form in my application. I also have a view component that creates an input field using [vue-google-maps](https://github.com/GuillaumeLeclerc/vue-google-maps).

I use this component within my  but there is no name attribute so my server does not recognize a submitted value.

How can I submit the data from the input field to my server? I am using Laravel 5.3.

```
<template>

    <place-input
            :place.sync="placeInput.place"
            :types.sync="placeInput.types"
            :component-restrictions.sync="placeInput.restrictions"
            class='form-control'
            label='Location: '
            name='location'
    ></place-input>

    <pre>{{ placeInput.place | json }}</pre>

</template>

<script>
    import { PlaceInput, Map } from 'vue-google-maps'

    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                placeInput: {
                    place: {
                        name: ''
                    },
                    types: [],
                    restrictions: {'country': 'usa'}
                }
            }
        },

        components: {
            PlaceInput
        },

        ready() {
        }
    }
</script>
<style>
    label { display: block; }
</style>
```

My Laravel form looks like this:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'CandidateController@store']) !!}
<div class='form-group'>
    {!! Form::label('email', 'Email:') !!}
    {!! Form::email('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class='form-group'>
    {!! Form::label('phone', 'Phone:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('phone', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class='form-group'>
    <location-input></location-input>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Where location-input is the vue-google-maps component that generates an input.

When I submit the form and dump the data to the screen no location data is available!

**on server**

```
$input = Request::all();
dd($input);
```

[image: no data from location-input avail on server side]

The raw input looks like this (the name attribute on the component does not add to the input field):

[image]

How do I submit the location-input data along with my form?

Comment: Is this live anywhere? If not, can you show the generated html?

Comment: updated the repo with a screenshot of the generated html. It is not live but the code repo is on github: https://github.com/connor11528/laravel-5.3-app

Answer (score 0):

I'd still like to see your generated html but I think the problem is that there's no `name` attribute on the input you're creating. Thus, it's not part of the posted data.

```
<place-input
        :place.sync="placeInput.place"
        :types.sync="placeInput.types"
        :component-restrictions.sync="placeInput.restrictions"
        class='form-control'
        name='location'
        label='Location: '
></place-input>
```

Comment: hey so I edited the question. Unfortunately adding a name attribute to the component does not cascade onto the input field itself. I added a pull request to the Vue component repo for name attribute: https://github.com/GuillaumeLeclerc/vue-google-maps/pull/123

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Vue but I believe there is a way to initialize it on an input that isn't generated as a template. So you should be able to just create your own html input and attach to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with vue but what about sending your form through vue and adding manually adding the location to the ajax request? Something like

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit">
//Your form
</form>
```

and

```
methods: {
    onSubmit: function (event) {
      //You can ajax your form data + manually add your location-input from your component
    }
  }
```

Would that solve your problem?